# Syfmony custom validator based on other Constraints

Tags: php, symfony, validation

How can one write a custom validator?

For example, I have this working code:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;



        $input = [
            null,   //fail
            0,      //fail
            1,      //fail
            2,      //fail
            "12",   //ok - string can be (at least 2 chars)
            20,     //ok
            50      //ok
        ];

        $constraint = new Assert\All([
            // the keys correspond to the keys in the input array
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\AtLeastOneOf([
                new Assert\Sequentially([
                    new Assert\Type(['type' => 'int']),
                    new Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(20)
                ]),
                new Assert\Sequentially([
                    new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string']),
                    new Assert\Length(2)
                ])
            ])
        ]);

        $validator = Validation::createValidator();

        $violations = $validator->validate($input, $constraint);
```

and I would like to pack the "checks" into one class, for example:

```php
        $input = [
            null,   //fail
            0,      //fail
            1,      //fail
            2,      //fail
            "12",   //ok - string can be (at least 2 chars)
            20,     //ok
            50      //ok
        ];

        $constraint = new Assert\All(
            new IdConstraint()
        );

        $validator = Validation::createValidator();

        $violations = $validator->validate($input, $constraint);
```

How should the class IdContrains or IdValidator look like? This is what I got so far:

```php
namespace App\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class IdConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The input "{{ string }}" contains invalid values.';
}
```

```php
namespace App\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class IdValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        //what to put here???
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put your logic and add violation if logic is broken. Also rtfm https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: I've read the fm but I can't figure out where to put the logic? I've posted the working logic up and not sure how to integrate that into the IdValidator class. This is why I ask for help.

Comment: Logic is in `validate` method. Do whatever you want with `$value`. If something is wrong - add/build violation to `this->context`.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following solution:

```php
namespace App\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class GroupValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $context = $this->context;

        $validator = $context->getValidator();
        $validations = $validator->validate($value, $constraint->getConstraints());

        if ($validations->count() > 0) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ value }}', (string)$value)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class IdConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The input "{{ value }}" contains invalid values.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return GroupValidator::class;
    }

    public function getConstraints()
    {
        return [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\AtLeastOneOf([
                new Assert\Sequentially([
                    new Assert\Type(['type' => 'int']),
                    new Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(20)
                ]),
                new Assert\Sequentially([
                    new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string']),
                    new Assert\Length(2)
                ])
            ])
        ];
    }
}
```

and in the test code:

```php
        $input = [
            null,   //fail
            0,      //fail
            1,      //fail
            2,      //fail
            "12",   //ok - string can be (at leas 2 chars)
            20,     //ok
            50      //ok
        ];

        $constraint = new Assert\All(
            new IdConstraint()
        );
```

As alternative, I see that in Symfony 5.1, using a [compound](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Compound.html) is possible, but I couldn't set there a simple error message.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Compound;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class IdConstraint1 extends Compound
{
    protected function getConstraints(array $options): array
    {
        return [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\AtLeastOneOf([
                new Assert\Sequentially([
                    new Assert\Type(['type' => 'int']),
                    new Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(20)
                ]),
                new Assert\Sequentially([
                    new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string']),
                    new Assert\Length(2)
                ])
            ])
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not specify the Symfony version you are using but if you have the maker bundle, the easiest way to create validators is `php bin/console make:validator`

As your validation code, you don't give a lot of details but from what I understand from your code, your validation could be something like this.

```
namespace App\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class IdValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $value = (int) $value;

        if ($value < 10) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use other Constraint to validate my Id value. The logic is in the question, maybe I didn't described it well enough. 
I've posted an answer with a solution I've created now and seems to be working well. Improvements of course are welcome:)

Comment: Yes, I see it in your own solution, I didn't understand correctly